# Why does My app Unfortunately Has Stopped

Tags: android-studio

[image]Error Shoing For this line

```
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
```

Error:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Toolbar cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
at com.example.mcq.CategoriesActivity.onCreate(CategoriesActivity.java:25)

Comment: Error showing in line no 24 in above image

Answer (score 1):

To use androidx, in your build.gradle file, add the following:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
}
```

Now you can use androidx toolbar as follows:

```
androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
```

Else if you have not refactored to androidx, then just use:

```
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

Hope you will find the solution.

Comment: check whether the Toolbar with id 'toolbar' is in the xml file 'activity_categories'

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrong library for the toolbar, check your import statement and replace

```
 import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
```

With:

```
import android.widget.Toolbar;
```

In your activity

Comment: That's what I am saying, the error is there but it is being caused by a wrong import statement, check the type of toolbar in you XML and the imported toolbar in your activity , they are different, go for the androidx toolbar it is better